# Cocos2d - CCScrollLayer within specific area with static buttons outside of Scroll Layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

I am trying to achieve the following:

- Within the scene, there to be a 'scrollable' area, containing clickable sprites/CCMenuItems.

  - Within the same scene there to be (outside of the 'scrollable' area) clickable sprites/CCMenuItems.

I have tried already using the CCScrollLayer extension for cocos2d, however the whole screen responds to a swipe, whereas I would like just a specific area to respond.
Also, when adding more buttons to the scene, which are not part of the CCScrollLayer I get multiple 'ccTouchesBegan Override' errors/crashes.

Here is an image to further explain what I seek:
[image: What I want]

If anyone can help me implement a 'Scroll Area' or even point me in the right direction I would appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own scrollable layer and register it as targeted touch dispatcher delegate. In this case in `touchBegan:withEvent:` method you will be able to detect, whether position of the touch is inside needed area (scrollable area, in your case).

Or check CCScrollable Layer code. I didn't use it before, maybe it can do the same for you, just need to register it as targeted touch dispatcher delegate instead of standard.